# How do I fix this code so that it posts the results of a PHP webcrawler into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am fooling around with some pre-written code for a PHP webcrawler. It is designed to read URLs off any specified website and post them to a page. I have been attempting to alter it to instead post the $url to a MySQL database. I feel like I am maybe 90% of the way there, as I am getting a connection to the database and record added. However, the record added is not the URL, but instead just an empty record. The webcrawler code worked in posting URLs to a webpage, but I am having trouble successfully fusing the two goals. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="lightonl"; // Mysql username 
$password="Gracias099"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="lightonl_my_db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="instruments"; // Table name 



include("simple_html_dom.php");
$crawled_urls=array();
$found_urls=array();

function rel2abs($rel, $base){
 if (parse_url($rel, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != ''){
  return $rel;
 }
 if ($rel[0]=='#' || $rel[0]=='?'){
  return $base.$rel;
 }
 extract(parse_url($base));
 $path = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '', $path);
 if ($rel[0] == '/'){
  $path = '';
 }
 $abs = "$host$path/$rel";
 $re = array('#(/.?/)#', '#/(?!..)[^/]+/../#');
 for($n=1; $n>0;$abs=preg_replace($re,'/', $abs,-1,$n)){}
 $abs=str_replace("../","",$abs);
 return $scheme.'://'.$abs;
}

function perfect_url($u,$b){
 $bp=parse_url($b);
 if(($bp['path']!="/" && $bp['path']!="") || $bp['path']==''){
  if($bp['scheme']==""){
   $scheme="http";
  }else{
   $scheme=$bp['scheme'];
  }
  $b=$scheme."://".$bp['host']."/";
 }
 if(substr($u,0,2)=="//"){
  $u="http:".$u;
 }
 if(substr($u,0,4)!="http"){
  $u=rel2abs($u,$b);
 }
 return $u;
}

function crawl_site($u){
 global $crawled_urls, $found_urls;
 $uen=urlencode($u);
 if((array_key_exists($uen,$crawled_urls)==0 || $crawled_urls[$uen] <     date("YmdHis",strtotime('-25 seconds', time())))){
  $html = file_get_html($u);
  $crawled_urls[$uen]=date("YmdHis");
  foreach($html->find("a") as $li){
   $url=perfect_url($li->href,$u);
   $enurl=urlencode($url);
   if($url!='' && substr($url,0,4)!="mail" && substr($url,0,4)!="java" &&     array_key_exists($enurl,$found_urls)==0){
    $found_urls[$enurl]=1;
    echo $url."<br/>";
   }
  }
 }
}

crawl_site("http://www.sfgate.com");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `lightonl_my_db`.`instruments` (`id`, `description`) VALUES   (NULL, '$url.');";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Again, I may be totally wrong, but everything seems to be functioning smoothly except that only one record is being added (instead of the multiple URLs returned by the webcrawler), and it's not the URL, but an empty record.

Comment: you should prepare the sql statements while you grab the data. you can either save the information in an array and in the next function you should start inserting the data into the database.

Comment: Thank you for this - it was probably a little bit overambitious for me to attempt this at my level, but that is a place to start.

Comment: @supthepunks what is the type of `description` in DB? is it varchar long enough to hold url?

Comment: varchar allows for 200 characters so yes, should definitely be enough with the urls being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to correct.

1. if your table has auto-increment, there is no need to specify id in insert.
2. Single dot appears from `(NULL, '$url.')`. There is a `.` after `$url`.
3. Where from do you get `$url` variable? It might be that there is no `$url` variable defined at the moment of insert.

Comment: Sorry, I just now edited my post to clarify that - the '$url' is what is returned by the webcrawler when searching for links on the specified webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Edited

Your sql should be found in the foreach loop so that each url is added to your db and don't forget to remove the extra ; and the . after $url:

```
      function crawl_site($u){
            global $crawled_urls, $found_urls;
            $uen=urlencode($u);
            if((array_key_exists($uen,$crawled_urls)==0 || $crawled_urls[$uen] < date("YmdHis",strtotime('-25 seconds', time())))){
                $html = file_get_html($u);
                $crawled_urls[$uen]=date("YmdHis");
                foreach($html->find("a") as $li){
                    $url=perfect_url($li->href,$u);
                    $enurl=urlencode($url);
                    if($url!='' && substr($url,0,4)!="mail" && substr($url,0,4)!="java" && array_key_exists($enurl,$found_urls)==0){
                        $found_urls[$enurl]=1;

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `lightonl_my_db`.`instruments` (`id`, `description`) VALUES   (NULL, '$url')";

                        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                            echo "New record created successfully";
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                        }

                        echo $url."<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you - still getting the period, however.

Comment: Please insert the entire code, your code is incomplete, may be there is an error in the crawler part

Comment: why the dot after $url ?

Comment: I pasted the end of the webcrawler code above, into the edited post.

Comment: If all the urls are concatenated as one single string, then you should find a way to separate them so that they can be added one by one in your database

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you for the tip - I will look into that. I also posted the complete code.

Comment: Also remove the NULL and `id` if your table has auto-increment for id

Comment: Hm...altered it and still running into the same issue. Does it appear to you that the urls are concatenated?

Comment: No, they are not concatenated in the foreach loop, try saving the $enurl instead in your sql and tell if it's working

Comment: Echo does, Jevgeni. I will try that, Elliot.

Comment: What is the datatype of the url column in your database table ?

Comment: @Elliot varchar(200)

Comment: @ElliottSadgamer Does not appear to work with $enurl, either.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, have you corrected the sql ? are you still getting a dot as result in your DB ?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO `lightonl_my_db`.`instruments` (`description`) VALUES   ('$url')";

Comment: @ElliottSadgamer Yeah, I don't know (tried that new version,too). Not even creating new records at this point. Will have to play around with it.